# Return the row maximum in a dictionary format

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to find out the maximum value in each row of a list and then return it in a dictionary format.I don't want to use max() here. so, What I tried is:

```
def maximum_value(my_list):
    k=my_list
    my_max_list= []
    dic={}
    for number in range(len(k)):
        for m in range(len(k[number])):
            my_max = k[number][0]
            a= k[number]
            for num in a:
                if (my_max < num):
                    my_max= num
       new_list1=['row', number ,'max',my_max]
       my_max_list.append(new_list1)
    return my_max_list
```

which outputs this:

```
[['row', 0, 'max', 13], ['row', 1, 'max', 12], ['row', 2, 'max', 20], ['row', 3, 'max', 8]]
```

I am almost into the answer but I want to get the output like this:

```
{'row 0 max': 13, 'row 1 max': 12, 'row 3 max': 8, 'row 2 max': 20}
```

so, to get this what I tried is:

```
from collections import defaultdict
for item in my_max_list:
    key= "".join(item[:-1])
    dic.setdefault(key,[]).append(item[-1])
```

But this is not helping me to get the above output. Any suggestions to get desired output please.  Thank you

The input I have given is:

```
my_list=[[5, 0, 0, 0, 13],[0, 12, 0, 0],[20, 0, 11, 0],[6, 0, 0, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below function.

I have made some changes is working like you want.

```
    def maximum_value(my_list):
        k=my_list
        dict={}
        for number in range(len(k)):
            for m in range(len(k[number])):
                my_max = k[number][0]
                a= k[number]
                for num in a:
                    if (my_max < num):
                        my_max= num
                key = 'row ' + `number` +' max'
                dict[key] = my_max
        return dict

    print maximum_value([[2,4,5,6,7,9],[6,4,7],[3,5,2]])
```

Following is the output

```
{'row 2 max': 5, 'row 1 max': 7, 'row 0 max': 9}
```

Hope this helps.

Glad if you could get this working

Following is the changed code You can use ordered dict

```
    from collections import OrderedDict
    def maximum_value(my_list):
        k=my_list
        my_max_list= []
        dict=OrderedDict()
        for number in range(len(k)):
            for m in range(len(k[number])):
                my_max = k[number][0]
                a= k[number]
                for num in a:
                    if (my_max < num):
                        my_max= num
                key = 'row ' + `number` +' max'
                dict[key] = my_max

        for k, v in dict.items():
        print k, v


    maximum_value([[5, 0, 0, 0, 13],[0, 12, 0, 0],[20, 0, 11, 0],[6, 0, 0, 8]])
```

Comment: Can you provide me your input

Comment: With your input It giving me the correct output. Let me check for sorting order

Comment: Edited : I have used OrderedDict & also loop through it to get each key value. As ordered dict format is somewhat different than you want. But may be useful

Comment: Thanks for different possibilities.

Comment: You are alwayz Welcome

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

my_list = [[5, 0, 0, 0, 13], [0, 12, 0, 0], [20, 0, 11, 0], [6, 0, 0, 8]]

my_list_max = OrderedDict()

for i, l in enumerate(my_list):
    my_max = l[0]
    for j in l:
        if j > my_max:
            my_max = j
    key = "row " + str(i) + " max"
    my_list_max[key] = my_max


print(my_list_max)
print(my_list_max['row 1 max'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) I am learning various possibilities. It should be in dictionary format. It outputs list format. Anyway thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome, but why do you think it outputs a `list`? It outputs an `OrderedDict` which is a subclass of the builtin dictionary. I've edited the answer to include a line at the end demonstrating this fact.

Comment: Yes its key value format. I was just thinking how to have like this {'row 2 max': 5} just a little bit change in pattern. Thank you any way. Thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem! :) Don't forget to give an upvote if you liked it. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104893/discussion-between-anmol-singh-jaggi-and-rocky25bee).